# Bash: Tab completion with cdable_vars

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bashrc

I've been relying on [this hack](http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/08/16/quickly-navigate-your-filesystem-from-the-command-line.html) for jumping around in the file system for a couple of years before finding out today that I can do the same thing using native Bash by activating the option `cdable_vars`.

The only thing I miss is tab completion. If I put this in my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
export mydir="$HOME/my/nested/directory"
```

Tab completion isn't expanding `mydir` when I try to `cd` into it from the prompt. Is there a way to activate this behavior in Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To activate this completion you need the bash-completion package.

If the package is installed (often by default) just add these lines in your .bashrc

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

If not: https://repology.org/project/bash-completion/versions

Comment: Weird, I've always used completion everywhere without having this installed. Anyway now it does what I want, thanks a lot!

Comment: The tab completion works with the `cd` command, though I use the path often with the `mv` command, which does not work. I wonder, if it could work as well.

Comment: @djangoliv Your [link](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) is broken